# Timer cancel when stop application EJB 3.0

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, timer, weblogic, ejb-3.0

On weblogic 10.3.4.0 (ejb 3.0) when I stop the application I want clean the timers on the predestroy fase on EJB Stateless.

but weblogic raise this message

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: [EJB:010193]Illegal call to EJBContext method. The bean is in "null" state. It cannot perform 'getting the Timer Service' action(s). Refer to the EJB specification for more details.
```

My preDestroy method is

```
@Resource 
private TimerService timerService;

@PreDestroy 
public void stopMyTimers() {
    if(timerService!=null){
        for(Timer timer : timerService.getTimers()) {
            if(timer!=null) timer.cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Exists something before PreDestroy when The bean is NOT in "null" state?

How I can cancel the timers when I stop the application?

Comment: It's easier to cancel them on startup in an `@PostConstruct` method

Comment: But the customer wants to cancel when the application stop.

Answer (score 0):

Adding something like the following should work:

```
@javax.ejb.Singleton
// you might need @javax.ejb.Startup as well
public class ShutdownController {

    @EJB
    private YourEjbWithTimers ejbWithTimers;

    @PreDestroy
    void shutdown() {
        ejbWithTimers.stopMyTimers();
    }

}
```

and change your `stopMyTimers` method to:

```
       // no annotation
       public void stopMyTimers() {
           // null tests not needed
           // - if something is null then it's broken
           for(Timer timer : timerService.getTimers()) {
               timer.cancel();
           }
       }
```